# Removing reference of some, out of selected objects using garbage collector in java

Tags: java, algorithm, garbage-collection

We know that the garbage collector is a program which runs on the JVM and gets rid of objects which are not being used by a Java application anymore. It is a form of automatic memory management. And the developer can only request the JVM to clean the objects but we cannot do explicitly.

This is supported by many textbooks and StackOverflow questions.

I got the following question on one of the java related fora:

> Define an algorithm for destroying 7 objects out of 20 objects made in memory using Garbage collector only.

My answer to the question would be the explanation cited above. Is it the correct answer (with some explanation)?

Comment: What do you mean by `destroying`? There is no such thing as destroying object in Java.

Comment: Wait, where did you get the question? You seem to imply it was on a forum but I couldn't find it. If it's homework then ask your teacher. The question doesn't seem like a very good one to me.

Comment: @tsolakp destroying here may mean cleaning the object from the memory.What it sounds like.

Comment: @Michael I got this question at the following link: https://www.glassdoor.co.in/Interview/1-There-are-20-objects-and-only-7-objects-needs-to-be-destroyed-Write-an-algorithm-to-destroy-only-7-objects-using-Garbag-QTN_1668775.htm

Comment: Again there is no such thing as "cleaning the object from the memory". Garbage collect an object, yes. If you want to to have 7 objects garbage collected then you just remove reference from them. It is another question if they want a prove that objects have been garbage collected.

Comment: If you have to call GC in your code, then you are doing it all wrong. as @tsolakp said, remove the reference. The questions you've linked are totally out of scope of the role, how do you go from memory management to simple regex, and for the love of god, what the hell is "best" architecture???